# Assigning value from dataframe to tkinter button and printing text

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, button, dynamic

Basically I want to assign text from a dataframe to dynamically created buttons and this code below works but, when I press the button only the the last value of the dataframe is printed. I have looked at multiple forums and questions on here but none of their solutions have worked for me, or I'm just not understanding the concepts. Can anyone help?

The code

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3 as sql

root = tk.Tk()

conn = sql.connect("C:\Sample_App\Sample.db")
conn.commit()

query = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT Description FROM PIZZA WHERE 
CATEGORYKEY='1-Pizza'", conn)

df = pd.DataFrame(query)

def print_text(button):
    text = button.cget("text")
    print(text)

rows=2

for i, item in df.iterrows():
    button = tk.Button(root, height=50, width=50, text=item, command=lambda : print_text(button))
    button.grid(row=rows, column=i)

root.mainloop()
```

So for example it creates three buttons with button 1, button 2, button 3. When I click any button "button 3" is the only text that is printed whereas I'd like to print text of the button printed.

Thank you guys in advance!